# How to create Customised User Permissions in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have this boolean field in my models.py called "status", the admin can only modify that as it is a boolean field. Now **I want some users to edit that field exclusively while all other fields need to be read-only**. In the django-admin interface, the user permissions are either completely editable or read-only.

How do I achieve my goal?

By the way, it is a leave management system project

```
#models.py

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

CHOICES = (('1','Earned Leave'),('2','Casual Leave'),('3','Sick Leave'),('4','Paid Leave'))

class Leave(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null =True)
    employee_ID = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    department = models.CharField(max_length = 15)
    designation = models.CharField(max_length = 15)
    type_of_leave = models.CharField(max_length = 15, choices = CHOICES, default = None)
    from_date = models.DateField()
    to_date = models.DateField()
    reporting_manager = models.CharField(max_length = 50, default = None)
    reason = models.CharField(max_length= 180)
    accepted = models.BooleanField(('status'), default=False)


def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

I'm new django and stackoverflow. Please point out if I need to be more/less descriptive in asking questions. thanks.

update***

views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from .models import Leave


content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Leave)
permission = Permission.objects.create(
   codename='can_change_status',
   name='Can Change Status',
   content_type=content_type,
)
```

Now, after giving code-name and name in my views.py, where should I specify to which field the user is authorized to edit?? The permission is being reflected in the admin User Permissions panel, but the function is not happening.

Answer (score 2):

Add the permision first like so:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from .models import Leave

content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Leave)
permission = Permission.objects.create(
   codename='can_change_status',
   name='Can Change Status',
   content_type=content_type,
)
```

and then when you create a user that youn want to have the permision use like below:

```
user = User.objects.create(...)
permission = Permission.objects.get(codename='can_change_status')
user.user_permissions.add(permission)
```

Then to check if user has permission to change status:

```
return request.user.has_perm('app.can_change_status')
'''This will return `True` if the user has the 'Change Status' permission
'''
```

Read More on [Django Docs v2 Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#programmatically-creating-permissions)

Comment: @kingraphall could you be specific in which files should I add the code.

Comment: In your views. And you can even check if user has permission in your templates.

Comment: I have added the above, the first chunk in my views.py of the app and the permission got reflected in the admin panel but the functioning didn't happen. Where do I specify which field to give permission to? And the rest two chunks of code where do I put them?

Comment: In your template, maybe where you show the details of the leave, just write `if user.has_perm('perm_name'): then display form field else:just display the default`

Comment: I've tried my best with your instructed code, in the admin console there's no template which I have defined. So I'm confused where to put the "if" loop code so as to make that permission function

Comment: Not in the admin my friend. In your app, probably where you show the leave details, the html template you create, the admin site is not considered here.

Comment: The thing is Leave details are only shown in the admin panel. In my app I just defined a modelform.